# DataGridView header not refreshing instantly when applying DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have added a filter to my datagridview using DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell class. i did the following

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in pDGV.Columns){
        col.HeaderCell = new DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell(col.HeaderCell);
        col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;                    
}
```

I have got the filter working correctly but I have one small niggling issue with the datagridview, the filter button doesnt show until I click another headercell.
How can I get to show the filter correctly as soon as the code to apply it runs? I have tried to call things like datagridview.invalidate() and datagridview.refresh() in the hope of refreshing the header row but that doesn't seem to work.

Regards
Amarino

Comment: I think you should invalidate your DGV or all the header cell one by one as soon as you are done with the filter. One of them should work. For cells use pDGV.InvalidateCell(rowIndex,colIndex);

Comment: Tried it...didn't work...

Comment: I managed to fix the issue by programmatically scrolling the datagridview horizontally, it seems its enough to wake up the control.


dataGridView1.HorizontalScrollingOffset = dataGridView1.HorizontalScrollingOffset + 10;